# DOM appendChild alternate

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, appendchild

I am creating a DOM element as follows;

```
var imgEle = document.createElement('img');
    imgEle.src = imgURL;         
    x.appendChild(imgEle);
```

Now for the last line instead of appending which creates multiple img elements each time the function is called, I want it to be replaced OR always be the first child element of x..

How should i do the same for crossbrowser compatibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var xChildren = x.childNodes;
if(xChildren[0])
   x.replaceChild(myIMG, xChildren[0]);
else
   x.appendChild(myIMG);
```

that should do the trick

We are grabbing all the child Elements of X, and then we check to see if the first of them is Defined. (If there are more than one you can also use the x.innerHTML method to remove them all at once). If it is defined we replace it with our newly created element, if it is not - we simply append the element.

EDIT: By creating and appending elements in a loop, you 're making your script a bit heavy - since it seems that you want to just change the image contained within x, why don't you simply resort to chaning the .src attribute?

```
var xChildren = x.childNodes;
var myIMG;    
if(xChildren[0])
   mIMG = xChildren[0]; //you should be sure that this is an image 
   // perhaps you might want to check its type.
else{
   mIMG = document.createElement("img");
   mIMG.src = "source";
   x.appendChild(mIMG);
}

//now the loop
while( your_condition )
    mIMG.src = "source of the image";
```

This way, you 're only using and editing one element.

Comment: Hey..u seem to have got this on target..thx a lot..Also i would have always preferred to use x.innerHTML..but in this case since i m facing some issues with that..so the way i m doing using createElement, .src..is it still possible to use x.innerHTML in the end somehow ?